# Setting up Blazor WASM API Security for Users

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4, blazor-webassembly

I'm fairly new to ASP.Net Core Identity and am running into a bit of a brain block and having a hard time tracking down an answer

I have a Blazor WASM site that has 2 APIs handling various things on the server.

I also have an Identity Server 4 instance up and running that also includes ASP.NET Core Identity.  Each API is set up in Identity Server to have it's own Scope, API_A and API_B. There is a Client set up in the Identity Server for directly interfacing with the APIs from postman. I also have some test users set up in Identity Server with various role claims.

My question is, when the Blazor WASM site goes to make an API call, do attach the User JWT as the bearer auth header value or do I need to setup the Blazor WASM site as a client and get a Client token and attach that as the bearer auth header value?

If I need to send the User token, how do I add the Scopes to that token to make sure it has access to call that API?

If I need to setup the Blazor WASM site as a client, how do I supply the users claims information with the client token so that the APIs know which user is calling the API and what Role they are a part of?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this covered in the BlazorDay 2020 Video. Starts at the 4:06 mark!
https://youtu.be/XoizucRjxgU?t=14772